# Serviço do Windows não inicia automaticamente

Tags: delphi, windows-service

Acabei de implementar um *Serviço do Windows* só que não consigo por ele para rodar de forma Automática quando o *windows* é iniciado. Não sei se foi alguma coias na programação ou alguma configuração do *windows*. Também não achei nada sobre esse assunto feito com *Delphi* aqui.

Código refente ao serviço

```
procedure ServiceController(CtrlCode: DWord); stdcall;
begin
  SvcAutoPub.Controller(CtrlCode);
end;

function TSvcAutoPub.GetServiceController: TServiceController;
begin
  Result := ServiceController;
end;

procedure TSvcAutoPub.ServiceExecute(Sender: TService);
begin
  Timer.Enabled := True;
  while not Terminated do
    ServiceThread.ProcessRequests(True); // fica em looping até alguém fechar o serviço

  Timer.Enabled := False;
end;

procedure TSvcAutoPub.ServiceStart(Sender: TService; var Started: Boolean);
begin
  if Connection.Connected = False then
  begin
    try
      Connection.Connected := True;
    finally
      tbParametos.Open;
      tbProcessos.Open;
      tbPublicacoes.Open;
      tbPonteiros.Open;
      tbAndamentos.Open;
      tbClientes.Open;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

As Propriedades do Serviço:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Se for alguma configuração do windows ai eu já não para onde vai.

Comment: Você registrou seu serviço no OS? [Installutil.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/pt-br/dotnet/framework/tools/installutil-exe-installer-tool)

Comment: sim ele funciona de boa só não inicia automático

Comment: Ele aparece na lista de serviços e nas configurações mostra a opção para iniciar automaticamente?

Comment: Claro se eu tive que instalar o serviço

Comment: Usei esse comando para instalar o serviço **“PATH_COMPLETO_DO_SERVIÇO /INSTALL”**.

Comment: Não esqueci de você não, estou lendo as documentações. Mas estou encontrando dificuldades e achar material de qualidade para o Delphi.

Comment: Já tenho 2 semanas procurando e nada...

Comment: Não achei nada a respeito, no momento. Vou continuar procurando se eu achar alguma coisa deixo uma resposta.

Comment: Blz, muito obrigado!

Comment: Ele arranca manualmente se voce for dar start dele na lista se serviços?

Comment: Sim. Quando eu abro a lista de serviços ele já esta lá só que parado tenho que apertar em iniciar.

Comment: Assim que possível estarei trazendo uma resposta que possivelmente resolverá seu problema. No momento estou longe de meu computador.

Comment: @EduMendonça a solução que apresentei não soluciona? Aqui esta perfeitamente executando automaticamente.

Comment: Eu não sei o que é... eu fiz a instalação como o @Jefferson Rudolf falou e fiz como você disse ele roda quando o windows abre só que  inicia com o status parado

Comment: Mas você iniciou ele uma primeira vez? Na minha resposta eu coloquei: `de um start nele faça seus testes se o serviço esta executando`

Comment: ele executa sim só que vem com statos parado. você está entendendo?
sabe la nos serviços aparece inciar, parar e reiniciar o meu como quando o windows iniciar ele inicia o serviço parado mesmo lá no Delphi eu setando para automático.
tenho que ir no serviço e apertar em iniciar para ele funcionar.

Answer (score 0):

Adicione no evento `OnCreate` a instrução: `Self.StartType := stBoot;`

Dessa forma o serviço será instalado e setado como "Automático", de um start nele faça seus testes se o serviço esta executando. Reiniciei o Windows e verifique se tudo ocorre como planejado.

Lembrando que esta propriedade pode ser setado no Object Inspector, o padrão dela é `stAuto` mas não inicializa o serviço automaticamente.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode incluir seu serviço na inicialização automática do Windows da seguinte forma:

Insira o código no evento `AfterInstall`

```
procedure TService.ServiceAfterInstall(Sender: TService);
var
  oRegEdit : TRegistry;
begin
  oRegEdit := TRegistry.Create(KEY_READ or KEY_WRITE);
  try
    oRegEdit.RootKey := HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE;

    if oRegEdit.OpenKey('\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\[ServiceName]',False) then
    begin
      oRegEdit.WriteString('Description','Serviço de sincronização do aplicativo');
      oRegEdit.CloseKey;
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(oRegEdit);
  end;
end;
```

Substitua o `[ServiceName]` pelo nome do seu serviço para que o Windows consiga inicializar o mesmo.
Assim após o seviço ser instalado, o mesmo será incluído na inicialização automática.

*Obs.: Deixe a propriedade `StartType` como `stAuto`*

Answer (score -1):

Vejo que você já usa um comando para instalar, mas tente usar o seguinte comando executando um .bat minimizado.

> SC CREATE NOME_DO_SERVICO binpath= "NOME_DO_EXECUTAVEL.exe" start= auto
>   displayname= "NOME_DE_EXIBICAO"

na parte do `start=auto` é onde ele vai ficar como inicialização automática.

Comment: vou testar e posto os resultados.

Comment: @EduMendonça deu certo quanto ao serviço?

Comment: em partes. Ele do modo que me informou ele inicia com o Windows só que ele está vindo parados.

Comment: @EduMendonça No seu objeto TService, verifique se a propriedade está como StartType=stAuto

Comment: A propriedade Está setada como `stAuto`.

Comment: Tens como mandar um print das propriedades que estão setadas no seu objeto

Comment: Na propriedade Interactive seta para True

Comment: Tipo de inicialização do serviço está como automático?

Comment: Está sim inclusive já fiz testes e no momento ele inicia com o Windows só que inicia com o Status Parado